# Mysql: Select all data between specified points

Tags: php, mysql, sql, between

I have a mysql tables with data connected to points. like this:

**tbl_user**

**tbl_earned_points**

**tbl_used_points**

I have a mysql query that select data of available points. This is the query:

```
SELECT
user.user_email_id AS userEmailId,
IFNULL(SUM(earn_points.earned_points),0) AS lifeTimePoints,
IFNULL((SUM(earn_points.earned_points) - (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(used_points.points_used),0) FROM tbl_used_points AS used_points WHERE used_points.user_id=earn_points.user_id)),0) AS availablePoints
FROM tbl_earned_points AS earn_points
RIGHT JOIN tbl_user AS user ON earn_points.user_id=user.user_id WHERE user.user_email_id <> '' AND user.user_email_id <> '0'
GROUP BY user.user_email_id
ORDER BY availablePoints ASC
```

From above query i am getting all emails & result like

```
userEmailId              lifeTimePoints     availablePoints
samal07@gmail.com        1745               1500
mistyorr_20@yahoo.com    100                75
bsfar@yahoo.com          85                 85
tgray@gmail.com          94                 90
lori_bag@yahoo.com       547                450
```

My problem is that I only need to get the rows availablePoints **between 80 TO 99**.

So my query would result like

```
 userEmailId        lifeTimePoints      availablePoints
 bsfar@yahoo.com        85              85
 tgray@gmail.com        94              90
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your WHERE clause:

```
AND availablePoints BETWEEN 80 AND 99
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'availablePoints' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BETWEEN` clause for `availablePoints`. Set your `availablePoints` whatever you want.

Comment: if i add "AND availablePoints BETWEEN 80 AND 99" in where clause then it gives
#1054 - Unknown column 'availablePoints' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you just need to add `WHERE` criteria.  However, you can also rewrite your query to remove the correlated subquery and just use `OUTER JOINs`:

```
SELECT  u.user_email,
    COALESCE(e.points,0) lifeTimePoints,
    COALESCE(a.points,0) availablePoints
FROM tbl_user AS u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(earned_points) points, user_id
        FROM tbl_earned_points
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) e ON u.user_id = e.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(points_used) points, user_id
        FROM tbl_used_points 
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE a.points between 80 and 99
```

If you'd prefer to use your existing query, you'll either need to wrap it in a subquery and use the column alias (`availablepoints`), or you'll need to use the entire `IFNULL` statement in your `WHERE` criteria.  *You cannot reference the column alias directly.*

Comment: Result is not getting correct using OUTER JOINS \n

SELECT user_id FROM 
( SELECT user_id, SUM(earned_points) as points FROM tbl_earned_points WHERE 1 GROUP BY user_id ) AS summary WHERE points BETWEEN 80 AND 99

from above query i am getting 1761 rows

& from your query i am getting only 25 rows

Comment: @user2046091 -- it shouldn't return the same results, it should return only with available point between 80 and 99.  However, if you run it without the `WHERE` criteria, then it should return the same number of results.